# how to select an empty table, but get one row in result (NULL + number)?

Tags: mysql

For example, i have an **empty** table 'A' with columns: `number(INT)` and `id`.
I know that in MySQL `null + number` returns `null`. However there is workaround using `IFNULL` function:

```
SELECT IFNULL(NULL, 0) + @number
```

would return @number. But if I try to select from an existing table, results are not the same:

```
SELECT IFNULL(number, 0) + @number FROM A
```

gives me a result with no rows selected.

How can i get MySQL to display one row with 'number' being a number, so I could insert minimal @number using `REPLACE` statement into table A?
Maybe there is another way..?

Comment: What do you expect to get if the table has 1 row and what if 2 ? I would expect you are trying to do a count or sum or some other aggregate on the whole table that you want to add a number to is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Perhaps sample data and expected output would help/

Comment: my plan is to save minimum initeger (> 0) related to an id in the table A. After some conditions(that doesn't matter), some of the rows (or all of them) in table A would be deleted, so, before inserting new row, i need to check what is the minimum 'number' in table A. i tried smth like this: REPLACE INTO A (SELECT MIN(IFNULL(number, 0)) + @number, id FROM A )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is indeed some aggregate function then something along these lines will always return 1 row

```
select MIN(IFNULL(tablesum.mysum, 0))
from 
  (select MIN(t.score) mysum from table t    
   union all 
   select @number as mysum
  ) tablesum
```

Reading your comment I think you want
Select min of a table (0 or 1 row), combine that with a row with a fixed number then sum those 1 or 2 rows:

```
select SUM(IFNULL(d.number, 0))
from 
  (select MIN(t.number) number from table t    
   union all 
   select @number as number
  ) d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't - you're selecting from an empty table. The number of rows returned is directly related to the number of rows in your table selection.

If you expect just a single row in A at any time, you could do something like this:

```
select IFNULL((select number from A limit 1), 0) + @number
```

But, I'd have to ask the broader question of what exactly you're trying to achieve with this query, because it's likely that it can be done in a better way.